# How to scroll efficiently in an NSScrollview with huge amount of data?

Tags: cocoa, scrollview, nsscrollview

I'm scrolling in a huge set of data points (CGPoints in a custom view, like a graph) and its obviously slow and laggy. Is there a common way to load and draw only the chunk of data I need to display? Does [[[myScrollview] documentView] documentVisibleRect] the trick? 
I also want to zoom in and out and therefore change the data point's detail. 
Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you do this is completely up to you. It's your custom view, you can draw whatever you like. Your view controller should keep track of the zoom level and current location and your view should just draw that part of the data.

There's nothing magic that's going to make this easier, you have to program it yourself.

Comment: And just to be sure: Is it the right way to zoom by changing the size of the custom view's frame (which is the document view)? So it can be virtually huge (10 million pixels wide or something like that) without being laggy?